# How i can add new attribute for the input submit in "form" wicket

Tags: wicket

Hello guys I have a small issue with wicket , I am new in wicket world so please help me :

[image: form markup]

[image: input markup]

the markup is need to add title to the input tag which is child to the form

the html is like this :

```
<div class="arena-record-button">
   <form wicket:id="showEditReservationPanelForm">
    <input class="arena-input-submit"  type="submit" wicket:id="editReservationButton" wicket:message="value:LabelEdit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

but any change I did in the html in the input tag does not appear when we prees on the button , otherwise i can add this code in the button constroctur and will work before i press the button :

this.add(new AttributeModifier("title", true, new Model("hello12")));

so the problem is after I press the button.

---

private void addEditReservationComponents(final ReservationDetailsPanel detailsPanel) {
Form<?> showEditReservationPanelForm = new Form("showEditReservationPanelForm");
showEditReservationPanelForm.setOutputMarkupId(true);
add(showEditReservationPanelForm);

```
    Button editReservationButton;
    boolean editReservation = isVisible(CONFIG_SHOW_EDIT_BUTTON) && reservation.isEditable();

    if (editReservation) {
        ApplicationBase app = (ApplicationBase) getApplication();
        DecorationParameters decorationParameters =
                new DecorationParameters(getSession().getLocale(), app.getPortalSite().getId(), Sets.newHashSet(decorations));
        EditReservationPanel editReservationPanel = new EditReservationPanel(EDIT_RESERVATION_PANEL_ID, decorationParameters, reservation,
                detailsPanel);
        editReservationPanel.setVisible(false);
        add(editReservationPanel);
        editReservationButton = new EditReservationButton(this, editReservationPanel, detailsPanel);
    } else {
        EmptyPanel editReservationPanel = new EmptyPanel(EDIT_RESERVATION_PANEL_ID);
        add(editReservationPanel);
        editReservationButton = new Button(EDIT_RESERVATION_BUTTON_ID);
        editReservationButton.setVisible(false);
    }

    showEditReservationPanelForm.add(editReservationButton);
}

/**
 * Indicates whether a component with the given portlet configuration key should be visible.
 *
 * @param key the portlet configuration key
 * @return <code>true</code> if and only if the portlet configuration for the given key returns <code>true</code>,
 * <code>false</code> otherwise
 */
private boolean isVisible(String key) {
    SessionBase session = (SessionBase) getSession();
    return session.getPortletConfigurationAsBoolean(key);
}

/**
 * Returns the configuration parameters for the indexed record panel.
 *
 * @param entityType the entity type to get the configuration for
 * @return the configuration parameters for the indexed record panel
 */
private IndexedRecordPanelConfigParams getIndexedRecordPanelConfigParams(EntityType entityType) {
    SessionBase session = (SessionBase) getSession();
    IndexedRecordPanelConfigParams configParams = new IndexedRecordPanelConfigParams(session, entityType);
    configParams.setDecorations(decorations);
    return configParams;
}

/**
 * This button provides the possibility to make the {@link EditReservationPanel} visible.
 */
private static class EditReservationButton extends IndicatingAjaxButton {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8740143889760682177L;
    private final ReservationListItemPanel listItemPanel;
    private final EditReservationPanel editReservationPanel;
    private final ReservationDetailsPanel reservationDetailsPanel;

    /**
     * Constructs a new {@link EditReservationButton}.
     *
     * @param listItemPanel           the {@link ReservationListItemPanel} to update on submit
     * @param editReservationPanel    the {@link EditReservationPanel} to make visible on submit
     * @param reservationDetailsPanel
     */
    private EditReservationButton(ReservationListItemPanel listItemPanel, EditReservationPanel editReservationPanel,
                                  ReservationDetailsPanel reservationDetailsPanel) {
        super(EDIT_RESERVATION_BUTTON_ID);
        this.listItemPanel = listItemPanel;
        this.editReservationPanel = editReservationPanel;
        this.reservationDetailsPanel = reservationDetailsPanel;
        setOutputMarkupId(true);
        setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxButton#onSubmit(org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget,
     * org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        setVisible(false);
        this.add(new AttributeModifier("title", true, new Model("hello12")));
        editReservationPanel.setVisible(true);
        editReservationPanel.setComponentsToMakeVisibleOnSave(this, reservationDetailsPanel);
        editReservationPanel.setComponentsToMakeVisibleOnCancel(this, reservationDetailsPanel);
        editReservationPanel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
        editReservationPanel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        if (target != null) {
            target.addComponent(editReservationPanel);
            target.addComponent(listItemPanel);
            target.addComponent(this);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add TextField to the Form in your Java code.

```
private void addEditReservationComponents(final ReservationDetailsPanel detailsPanel) {
  Form<MyObject> showEditReservationPanelForm = new Form<MyObject>("showEditReservationPanelForm");
  showEditReservationPanelForm.setOutputMarkupId(true);
  add(showEditReservationPanelForm);

  // new stuff starts here
  TextField input = new TextField("editReservationButton", someModel);
  input.add(AttributeAppender.append("title", Model.of("Some text")));
  showEditReservationPanelForm.add(input);
  // ...
}
```

P.S. I've also changed `Object` (java.lang.Object ?!) to `MyObject`. I doubt you want to use `java.lang.Object` as a model object backing your Form.

Comment: Thanks , Martin,
Your code worked but it changes the form (the parent ) , i would like to change the input tag which is in the form tag 
Any idea please ?

Comment: Sorry. I've missed that part. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you put still same, I will update my post so you see the whole class